# Why is Hizb ut-Tahrir outlawed in Muslim countries but allowed in Western Countries?

Tags: international-relations, middle-east

Hizb ut Tahrir is an International, Pan-Islamist Organization which aims to unite the Muslims under the Caliphate (as its promised with them in prophecies) and its proposed state would have *Sharia* law and do *Dawah* to non-Muslims. [1](http://www.start.umd.edu/research-projects/hizb-ut-tahrir-al-islami-challenge-non-violent-radical-islam) Hizb-ut-Tahrir can be described as "revolutionary" (mainly due to misunderstanding of Caliphate's concept in majority of countries - even in Muslim world) but "Non-violent" [2](http://www.start.umd.edu/research-projects/hizb-ut-tahrir-al-islami-challenge-non-violent-radical-islam)

All but 3 Arab countries have banned Hizb-ut-Tahrir. Similarly, in Pakistan and Turkey, this organization is banned as well, while on the other hand, its successfully operating in Western Countries from USA to Australia.

What is the reason behind it? (*My naive understanding is that all the Muslim "countries" rulers fear from the concept of Caliphate resulting in them losing their seats to a unified ruler while western countries have no such a fear*)

References

1. http://www.hizb.org.uk/islamic-culture/can-the-muslim-world-really-unite
2. [Media office of Hizb - Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20070927200032/http://www.hizb-ut-tahrir.info/english/about.htm#2)
3. [*McCauley, Clark; Karagiannis, Emmanuel (2009).* "Hizb ut-Tahrir al-Islami: The Challenge of a Non-Violent Radical Islam". National Consortium for the Study of Terrorism and Responses to Terrorism.](http://www.start.umd.edu/research-projects/hizb-ut-tahrir-al-islami-challenge-non-violent-radical-islam)

Answer (score 24):

Most Muslim countries are governed by authoritarian regimes. An authoritarian regime usually outlaws any organizations which threaten their authority.

Most Western countries, on the other hand, are democracies. Freedom of speech and freedom of association are considered important values in democracies.  That usually means that political organizations are tolerated unless they commit crimes.

But this doesn't mean that Hizb-ut-Tahrir does completely fly under the radar of Western governments. For example, the German ministry of interior outlawed the organization in 2003 for standing against international understanding and advocating violence. That ban was confirmed to be legal by [a court decision (German source)](http://lexetius.com/2006,604). [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hizb_ut-Tahrir#Western_countries), Denmark, Spain and France also took legal measure to outlaw the organization in whole or in parts, while the United Kingdom still tolerates the group as "radical, but to date non-violent Islamist group".

Comment: Thanks! - Yeah this authoritarian thing came as main reason to my mind as well

Comment: Tunisia and Indonesia are majorly muslim and are at least somewhat democratic. Are such groups also illegal there ?

Comment: It's "banned". However, they still linger. Not really sure what it means by "banned" there. I don't think you go to jail for just being a member.